# Rubber washer in camelback Antidote Reservoir 1.5L

Tags: bags, hydration

I've got this camelback blue waterbag for my bike rucksack. I removed the black rubber washer from the opening wheel for cleaning and now i cannot put it back properly. Could you send me close up photos showing where exactly the washer should be and on what side? A vid would be great, too

[image: From https://images.yswcdn.com/-2867688965004507840-ql-85/700/500/ay/trisports/camelbak-antidote-replacement-reservoir-42.jpg]

Comment: Probably this one: Camelbak Antidote Reservoir 1.5L Neutral

Comment: What's the "opening wheel"  ?  Is it the big threadded lid used for filling the bag?   I've added a generic stock photo if it helps - consider replacing with a photo showing the problem.

Comment: yeah that's basically the model, only the reservoir is a bit smaller. and yeah, lid. I tend to forget everything these days so I forgot the word "lid".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing complicated about how it fits. Here's my cap seal for reference. [image: camelbak bladder seal]

Comment: cheers man. I'll try it at home. I don't know why it hasn't worked for me so far.

Comment: @greg Maybe its been stretched or deformed in the removal?  If so you might be up for either a replacement lid or a whole replacement liner bag.  Remember, never use anything but plain pure water in these.  That means no sports drinks, no flavours, powders or tablets.  Leave them completely open to air dry, or if you intend on using the next day I've heard you can freeze them **empty** to stop mould.  They still need a proper clean at the end of the weekend.

Comment: Sometimes you can get rubber to return to its normal shape and size by submerging in boiling water.

Comment: Oh and my sink is a right mess because it's in my utility room and I've been painting my daughter's bedroom - hence the paint splashes.

Comment: I put there dilluted apple juice hence the mould and necessity to clean it. Just don't like drinking pure water. will do better next time!

Comment: Man, thank you a lot for that picture! Had a hard time fixing it back and also finding the right picture for that o ring for my camelbak! Topicstarter, thank you a lot as well!